# set gameobject inactive with smallest value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't seem to find a answer to this, i believe it's impossible to do by now.

i have a player that collects gameobjects, when the gameobjects are collected they become a child of the player. All gameobjects have a rigidbody with different mass but duplicate gameobjects have the same mass offcourse.

The player grows in mass when gameobjects are collected.

What i want to do is when the player reaches a certain amount of mass and collect another gameobject i want the gameobject with smallest mass to set inactive.

I already got this:

```
                     Component[] objects = GetComponentsInChildren(typeof(Rigidbody), false);
                     foreach (Rigidbody joint in objects)
                     {
                         float smallest = Mathf.Min(joint.mass);
                         if (smallest <= mass / 100 && joint.gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
                         {
                             int i = 0;
                             bool plus = false;
                             while (i < transform.childCount)
                             {
                                 if (transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.activeInHierarchy && plus == false)
                                 {

                                     transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(false);
                                     Debug.Log("disabled");
                                     plus = true;
                                 }

                                     i++;
                             }
                         }
                     }
```

This sets the first child gameobject of the player inactive after it reaches a certain amount of mass.

but this isn't what i really want, i want to get the gameobject with the smallest mass to set inactive but i can't convert the "float smallest = Mathf.Min(joint.mass);" back to an gameobject.

Is this possible to achieve or is it just impossible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it is possible my friend

```
using System.Linq // < --- at top of script

List<Rigidbody> objects = GetComponentsInChildren<Rigidbody>(false)
    .OrderBy(i => i.mass)
    .ToList();
Rigidbody smallest = objects.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: OMG i didn't knew about System.Linq. guess i have to learn alot more. That totally worked, been stuck for this for like 2 days thank you very mutch thumbs up!!